# How to factory reset /delete all users in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, user-management, administration

I am new to ubuntu. I purchased a laptop today which comes with Ubuntu preinstalled on it. On starting it asked me to create a user with a password. After logging in, I found that its specifications are totally different from what I expected. Is there any way to delete this user and restore the laptop to the factory state so that I can return it to seller?

Comment: Just curious... what specs are different than what you expected? Cheers, Al

Comment: The website description was showing i3-5th generation but actually it's 4th generation. Also, it was claimed to have HD anti-glare display but the screen is too dull. Also, the touchpad seems to have some issue. I guess they have given me the old version of the same model.

Comment: Experts, Please help! I could not find the solution yet.

Comment: If you haven't created any documents, or added any pictures/music, don't worry about it. Just return it and let them restore it to factory specs using the restore functionality (if it was built that way, otherwise they'll just have to reinstall). Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo deluser --remove-all-files username
```

replace the username with the user you want to delete

If you do not have the access to GUI press `ctrl+alt+f1` you get the terminal do login and execute the following command

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

This resets the everything ...... just like firstime it asks for the creating the user

After Completion of Command press `ctrl+alt+f7` to go back to gui....

Comment: I feel it should not work, as right now computer has only one user and I am logged-in with same username. I wonder whether it will allow me to delete this?

Comment: @VikasBharti well in that case have look into this link https://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/how-to-reset-ubuntugnome-settings-to-defaults-without-re-installing/